# SQL query to compare 2 date values

Tags: sql, impala

I want to compare 2 fields in Impala/Hive in the where condition of the query.
Below is one sample value from each column

- column_1 = 202003     <- Integer
- column_2 = '03/01/2020'  <- String

I want to compare these 2 columns. 
"where column_1 = column_2" should return a true in the above case since they are the same year and same month.

How can I write a where condition to compare the 2 columns. thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
column1 = concat(right(column_2, 4), left(column_2, 2))
```